# Azure ARM VM creation with Network Security Groups

Tags: azure, squid, http-proxy, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

I have a network with enabled Network Security Groups where I deny Outbound Port 80 and 443. All Outbound traffic is managed through a Squid Proxy.

Now, I want to create a new Virtual Machine in this Network using the Azure ARM templates using the resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines. The problem is that after creation of the Azure Storage Account the VM can't connect to it as the Outbound Port 80 and 443 are denied.

Is it possible to give the resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines some proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a custom script extension to call a script to change the proxy settings on the VM itself after VM creation has completed.